# .sequelizerc with ESM modules doesn't work with @babel/register and @babel/preset-env

Tags: sequelize.js, babeljs, es6-modules, sequelize-cli

If I change in .sequelizerc file babel packages to @babel/register and @babel/preset-env sequelize CLI stops working (the following code works as is).

```
require("babel-register")({
    presets: [["babel-preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
});
// I want this to be:
// require("@babel/register")({
//     presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]], 
// });

const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
    config: path.resolve("dist/server/config", "config.js"),
    "models-path": path.resolve(
        "dist/server/models/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME
    ),
    "seeders-path": path.resolve(
        "dist/server/seeders/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME
    ),
    "migrations-path": path.resolve(
        "dist/server/migrations/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME
    ),
};
```

When calling `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`
The ESM imports inside migrations then throw error:

> ERROR: require() of ES Module
> C:...\dist\server\migrations\globalData\20230602000000-langs.js from
> C:...\node_modules\umzug\lib\migration.js not supported. Instead
> change the require of 20230602000000-langs.js in
> C:...\node_modules\umzug\lib\migration.js to a dynamic import() which
> is available in all CommonJS modules.

Comment: You’re mixing module systems. If you want to use esm in your migrations then umzug might perform better with explicit .mjs extensions: https://github.com/sequelize/umzug/tree/main/examples/2.es-modules. You haven’t shared your migration files or your package.json type.

Comment: @morganney yes I am mixing module systems, that's why I use the babel. The old packages work, the new one \@babel packages don't. And my question is how to make it work with \@babel packages.

Comment: Babel won’t help you if you’re mixing module systems. If you are intentionally mixing module systems you need to account for that yourself in how you cross boundaries.

Comment: How come it works then when I use the old version?

Comment: I don’t know, it’s not my project and I don’t have insight into how you are doing things. Did you change node versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use `"babel-register"` and `"babel-preset-env"`, but with Babel 7, these packages were scoped under the `@babel` namespace. So, the corrected code uses [`"@babel/register"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-register) and [`"@babel/preset-env"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-env) instead.

You can also move the Babel configuration to a separate file ([`.babelrc`](https://babeljs.io/docs/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading)): that would ensure that Babel's behavior is consistent across your entire project. In your code, the configuration is inline within [`.sequelizerc`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#the-sequelizerc-file), which might lead to discrepancies if other parts of your code were relying on different Babel settings.

So, first install `@babel/register` and `@babel/preset-env`

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/register @babel/preset-env
```

Then create a `.babelrc` file in your project's root directory with the following content:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]
  ]
}
```

That configuration tells Babel to use the `@babel/preset-env` preset, which transpiles your code to a version of JavaScript compatible with your current version of Node.js.

Finally, update `.sequelizerc` to Use `@babel/register`

```js
require("@babel/register");

const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  config: path.resolve("dist/server/config", "config.js"),
  "models-path": path.resolve("dist/server/models/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME),
  "seeders-path": path.resolve("dist/server/seeders/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve("dist/server/migrations/" + process.env.MICROSERVICE_NAME),
};
```

When Sequelize CLI runs the migrations, it needs the files to be transpiled if they are using syntax not supported in the current Node.js environment. By requiring `@babel/register` at the beginning of the `.sequelizerc` file, you are ensuring that this transpilation happens automatically as files are `require`d. The original configuration may not have been set up correctly to perform this on-the-fly transpilation, leading to the error.

---

If the error persists, that suggests an incompatibility between the way that the migration files are being loaded and the module system being used ([CommonJS vs ES Modules](https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/), as detailed by [Kingsley Ubah](https://github.com/KingsleyUbah)).

If your migrations are written using ES module syntax (`import`/`export`), consider converting them to CommonJS (`require`/`module.exports`). That can avoid conflicts with the way the migrations are loaded.

Or, you could try creating a bootstrap file that sets up Babel and then runs the Sequelize CLI command. That might give you more control over the environment in which the command is run.

Create a file like `run-migrations.js`:

```js
require('@babel/register')({
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  ],
});
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

execSync('npx sequelize-cli db:migrate', { stdio: 'inherit' });
```

Then you can run your migrations with `node run-migrations.js`.

---

As a temporary workaround, you might try using the [`esm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) package to enable ES module syntax in your migration files.

---

> I guess I will transpile it via typescript (which I use anyways) to commonJs and do some shannanigans for it to work. And Ill use this till the sequelize guys fix this.

That is one possibility indeed: work around the problem by using TypeScript to transpile the code to CommonJS format, rather than relying on Babel for that task.

You would first need to make sure your `tsconfig.json` file is set up to transpile your TypeScript code to CommonJS modules. That might look something like:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    // other options
    },
    // rest of the configuration
}
```

Run the TypeScript compiler to transpile your migration files (and potentially other parts of your codebase) to CommonJS. That can be done as part of your build process.

You may need to update your `.sequelizerc` file or other Sequelize configuration to point to the transpiled files, depending on how your build process is set up.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @digitalniweb Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: updated to 18.17.1 via nvm. Still same result.

Comment: I guess Ill transpile it via typescript (which I use anyways) to commonJs and do some shannanigans for it to work. And Ill use this till the sequelize guys fix this.

Comment: @digitalniweb Good call. I have edited the answer to illustrate what that work around could look like.